# google sheet data filter for last a few days

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet to log what I do at work every day. 
for example
[no filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAduZ.png)

I managed to figure out how to filter it by today.
highlight colon -> data -> filter -> date is today
for example:
[only today](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsO8D.png)

but I could not figure out how to filter it by the last x number of days
for example:
[goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWHz7.png)

I guess I will need to make a custom filter, but I have a really hard time figuring out how to make custom filters in google sheet.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this in two ways. One with a filter view, and one with a formula you could also use. Both are in my [example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dCS3Z4Qs0vaOi-azdLzZn0VFARIXAkJZw5vlqH98TQ0/edit?usp=sharing) based on your provided data.

Filter View:

To view my example use the above link and go to the sheet "Filtered". Then apply "Filter recent days" which is a filter I created. I created [this filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4aRZ.png) by filtering column A for the condition "Date is after". I then chose "exact date..." which allows formula input. The formula I used was `=TODAY()-4` which simply filters the data for every instance of column A which is after 4 days ago.

Filter formula:

To accomplish this, I left the original data in columns A and B. Then in C5, I entered the formula `=FILTER(A3:B,A3:A>TODAY()-4)`, which uses basically the same method as above. This will produce a separate output next to your original data with only the recent entries.
I also took this a step further by moving the formula down a cell, and then replacing the `4` in the formula with `D2`. Now you can change the number in D2 to change how many days it displays.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The filter view one is exactly what I need.